Dark patches on painted surface over insulated plasterboard
I have insulated the wall of one room with two exterior facing walls. I did this using insulated plasterboard (37.5mm) which I fuxed to the walls by drilling holes in the walls and fixing with wall anchors (90mm x 8mm). I then plastered over the plasterboard (2 coats of skimcoat) and then applied a mist-coat of paint. (1 part paint, 1 part water)
I have painted the first normal coat, and now that the paint has dried I am seeing some unsightly dark patches along the wall. These patches are at the points where the wall-anchors are stuck in.
Is there anything I can do about this?
(I was hoping just that more coats of paint would be required, or that maybe, being colder and less insulated, these spots just need a bit longer to fully dry, but thought I better get some advice before continuing! (in case I have to sand off the paint even the plaster itself))


This is all a new process to me, but I would allow 24 hours for drying and apply another non thinned coat of paint.

Did you skimcoat over the entire wall?  Is the skim thicker at the anchors, i.e. are they very countersunk?

You may want to also put a coat of stain-blocking primer on the wall before doing any more finish coats.  That should block any color discoloration due to those anchors.  But I'd suggest painting the whole wall to give everything an even base and not look splotchy if you only prime the impacted spots.

@Huesmann - I did, but I don't think it was much thicker at the anchors, a mm or two countersunk at the most (i.e. not really noticeably so). Once plastered there were no tell-tale signs.

Thanks for the input folks.
When I returned from work later in the day after asking this question, I saw that the spots in the photo had disappeared as did a few others, but others had appeared.
So I decided to give it another day or two to see what happened and they too faded, as did a few larger patches, eventually all the patches were gone.
I put it down to my original guess that those patches were colder and therefore took a bit longer to completely dry. So I ended up just painting the second finish coat and now everything looks fine.
